# Is variant human better than standard human if all my ability scores are odd?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, feats, ability-scores

So if I rolled stats of 17, 15, 15, 15, 14 and 13, is this one of those rare cases where the normal Human "+1 to everything" is going to be more useful than the Variant Human +1 +1 and a feat?

I'm wondering basically how important high secondary stats is vs a feat like Lucky, Alert, Sharpshooter and Resilient, which are the ones I am looking at.

Comment: Do you have a class in mind already?

Comment: I have been looking at tons of different things to work off of, with many different characters springing to mind. I may have finally settled on a Battlemaster Fighter with a Longbow and sword-and-board, versatile but good at what he does as well. 

Either that or far more specialized, like a Rogue with Sharpshooter to really be a mobile sniper that hides well. Always keeping the bow though

Comment: can you narrow the scope on what is "better" in your model of character creation? Put another way: in the question the implication is that you generally consider the feat better than four +1s, but the all-odd roll may be an exception. What, to your mind, makes the feat usually better?

Comment: This is too broad, as the answer is class dependent, and in part campaign dependent.  At least defining the class and archetype would bound the question well enough for discrete answers.

Answer (score 10):

This will vary somewhat from campaign-to-campaign or DM-to-DM, but those tertiary stats are usually low priorities because they won't come up with the same frequency as your primaries. It's possible to build, for instance, a high-INT barbarian, but the party will still probably run go to the wizard or the bard for History checks and loot identification anyway. Running multiple characters with the same strengths is redundant (which can be good!), but might also lead to characters stepping on each others' toes. Ultimately, the +1 to your frequently unused skills helps, but not usually by much.

On the other hand, you might have a build in mind that relies on multiple attributes- a part monk with a dip in warlock and some wizard buffs, for instance, might have an interest in keeping more than 2 or 3 high stats. In these cases, however, you plainly do not have enough stat points over the course of a normal adventuring career to allot to become great at all of these things. You only really need enough to get into those classes, and then you'll likely end up using the chassis from your other classes.

Meanwhile, 5e's feats are *very* potent. Specifically looking at the feats you mention, Lucky allows you to pre-roll a few dice for a given day. This could very easily outpace the +1 to whatever rarely used niche stat, and still synergizes beautifully with your strengths anyway. Alert can wreck an ambusher's day and comes in useful even in easy encounters, Sharpshooter gives you interesting choices to make in combat, and the +2 initial bonus from Resilient already probably outpaces the bonus of the tertiary stat and gets better over time.

In the end, what you choose relies on what you want out of your character. I'd argue the depth of options available from taking a variant human feat greatly outweigh the statistical bonus you'd receive as the generic human.

Comment: I would agree, but the question comes from seeing how much value people put into +1s that seem minor and inconsequential to me, at least from looking at builds from past editions. I'd rather get something interesting like Magic Initiate or Alert, something character-defining, but then I look at all the 15s and think that I have always undervalued +1s that others seem to really think matter.

Comment: @Kiri Beware using experience with past editions. They're not comparable.

Comment: @Eladri Did you mean re-roll or pre-roll for Lucky feat?  As I read it, the pre-roll applies to Divination magic, proactive, whereas the re-roll applies to the Lucky feat, reactive.

Comment: @Korvin Now that you bring up the issue, you might be right; I don't have the book on me right now, so I can't reference. I'd still argue the Lucky feat's ability to override disadvantage or other bad rolls would probably be more useful than a +1 to less-used skills.

Comment: @Eladri In a lot of ways, it's a very strong feat, but it is only useable a few times per day.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes.

In most builds, you're only going to care about two or three stats.  Increasing the others is usually unnecessary unless your group is seriously lacking in some department.  For example, a stereotypical Barbarian build will care about Str and Con, and maybe Dex as well.  Getting an extra +1 in the mental stats for such a character would be nice, but isn't going to improve the overall effectiveness of the build.

A feat, however, is always great.  Feats are really powerful and important, and a feat is always going to be better than a +1 to a few stats that you rarely use.  A pretty standard choice when you have a lot of odd stats and choose Variant Human is to put your 2 +1s in your most important stats, and then take a feat that gives you a +1 in the other, along with other benefits.

There is probably some build out there that can usefully use all 6 stats and can work better with the standard human, but that's going to be the exception to the rule.